# Largest set enclose in a polytope

Tags: optimization, polytopes

I would like to solve the following (apparently not so simple) problem.

Given the following sets:

$\mathcal{X} = \{ x \in R^n | Ax \leq b \}$

$\mathcal{Y} = \{ y \in R^n | C y \leq d \}$

I would like to find the largest subset $\tilde{\mathcal{X}} \subseteq \mathcal{X} $ such that the set $\tilde{\mathcal{Y}}$, defined as the codomain of the smooth function

$ F(x) :  \tilde{\mathcal{X}} \rightarrow  \tilde{\mathcal{Y}}$

is a subset of $\mathcal{Y}$, i.e. $\tilde{\mathcal{Y}} \subseteq \mathcal{Y}$.

When I say largest subset I mean the subset with the maximum area.

NOTE: It is also fine parametrize the $\tilde{\mathcal{X}}$ such that $\tilde{\mathcal{X}}(s) = \{ x \in R^n , s \in R^p \; | \; Ax -b \leq s \; ; \; s \leq 0  \}$. In this case the problem would be to find the values of $s$ that maximize the area of $\tilde{\mathcal{X}}(s)$ and such that  $\tilde{\mathcal{Y}}(s) \subseteq \mathcal{Y}$.

Comment: what is $F(x)$?

Comment: $F(x)$ is a smooth function that maps a point in $\tilde{\mathcal{X}}$ to a point in $\tilde{\mathcal{Y}}$.